# New to Javascript (Svelte) - how do functions have access to variables?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I am new to Javascript, but have a few years of experience with Python.
I have been following the [7GUIS](https://eugenkiss.github.io/7guis/tasks#flight) exercises, to understand basic frontend development.

I have a very small svelte file, as follows:

```
<script>
let t1 = "2022-09-11" ;
let t2 = "2022-09-12" ;

function compareDates(){
  if (t2 < t1) {
    console.log("Warning! You return before you fly!")
  }
}
</script>

<input type="date" bind:value={t1} on:change={compareDates}>
<input type="date" bind:value={t2} on:change={compareDates}>
```

There are two date selection inputs, `t1` and `t2`. Each time they are changed, the function `compareDates` checks to see if `t2` < `t1`. If it is, it logs a string in the console.

But **how does `compareChange` have access to these variables?**
My guess, is that the `<script></script>` area is a singular namespace.
If that is the case, is this best practice? Or would it be better to pass t1 and t2 from the "input objects"* somehow?

- I assume the HTML elements can be accessed, I believe through `bind:this={}`

Comment: Related if not duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: FWIW, this would work exactly the same in Python (as far as this is comparable)…

Comment: @deceze in the sense that `<script></script>` is the equivalent of a namespace?

Comment: Yes, it's *one scope*.

Comment: Welcome to the `window`

Comment: @IanBrindley, so if i'm understanding correctly,
variables inside `<script></script>` become members of the `window` object.
However, enclosing variables within curly braces e.g. `<script>{ let t1 = "" }</script>` means they are in a separate scope, and cannot be accessed by HTML elements?

Comment: no they are not in `window` object!! Svelte constructs a class from your component code so all of that code is within the same _enclosure_ as H.B. linked

Comment: Thanks @StephaneVanraes, that makes sense. 
To clarify, that class has access to global components, like `console` and `document`. Is there a way to see what is contained in the class?

Comment: you can look at the compiled code if you want, but in general just what you write in your style block

Comment: Go to [svelte repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/), paste your code. On the right “output panel”, find the “js output” tab, there you can see the compiled code.

Comment: Svelte is not normal JS, it’s compiler magic that bends JS semantics (in a very elegant way IMO) to serve the purpose of fast web app authoring. So don’t bother because what you learn about svelte doesn’t apply to normal JS.

Comment: @rorance_ if you're curious to see the scopes and what they contain, put a debugger statement inside the compareDates function, then open your browser's devtools. If you then trigger that function, the browser will pause the program and expose a step debugger. At that point, you can look at the scope and every variable it contains, while also manually stepping through your code.